# Cannot import Cocoapod into Dynamic Framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am creating a project in Xcode8 which has a widget extension.  I am trying to factor out my service API code (some class functions that hit a web API written in Swift) into a dynamic Framework.

I have created the Framework through the template and dragged my ServiceAPI.swift file/code to it.  Made sure that the file was included in the framework target.

This code relies on `SwiftyJSON` to parse the JSON it gets from the web.  Now, before moving the code into the framework, SwiftyJSON was compiled and running fine in my application target.  After moving it I get a linker error:

> ld: framework not found SwiftyJSON
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried several things to fix it.  I thought possibly setting the framework search paths might work but no paths I added fixed the issue.

So what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using cocoapods. In that case you can simply add your framework as a target for the Pod, SwiftyJSON. To do this simply edit your `Podfile` to include the second target.

```
target 'MyApplication' do
    pod 'SwifyJSON'
end

target 'MyFramework' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

Comment: this was the problem.  amending the pod file to include the new Framework and running Pod Install fixed it.